# addAccountExplicitly throws SecurityException because com.google.android.gm is not allowed to perform GET_ACCOUNTS

Tags: android, android-syncadapter, android-securityexception

My app uses SyncAdapters to sync data in the background. On a device running OS 8.0 and setup for Android for Work managed profile, calling addAccountExplicitly throws a SecurityException and fails to add the account properly.

Here is the callstack:

```
11-28 17:28:00.182 7291-7291/com.example.android.basicsyncadapter E/CreateSyncAccount: Failed
   java.lang.SecurityException: com.google.android.gm from uid 10074 not allowed to perform GET_ACCOUNTS
      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1942)
      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1888)
      at android.accounts.IAccountManager$Stub$Proxy.addAccountExplicitly(IAccountManager.java:1205)
      at android.accounts.AccountManager.addAccountExplicitly(AccountManager.java:875)
      at com.example.android.basicsyncadapter.SyncUtils.CreateSyncAccount(SyncUtils.java:58)
      at com.example.android.basicsyncadapter.EntryListFragment.onAttach(EntryListFragment.java:148)
```

I have reproduced the failure using two GitHub projects running 8.0 on a Pixel:
fingerprint=google/marlin/marlin:8.0.0/OPR3.170623.013/4397526:user/release-keys

GitHub apps:

1. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testdpc
2. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BasicSyncAdapter

Here are the steps to reproduce throwing the above exception:

1. Factory reset the device and wait for the out-of-box screen to appear.
2. Install the application android-testdpc. Complete setting up the device for Android for Work managed profile.
3. Do not change any policies and do not restart the device.
4. Install the application android-BasicSyncAdapter and launch it.
5. Logcat will capture

> I am_crash: [7489,0,com.example.android.basicsyncadapter,950582854,java.lang.SecurityException,com.google.android.gm from uid 10075 not allowed to perform GET_ACCOUNTS,Parcel.java,1942]

Additional Notes:

- I am seeing the SecurityException being thrown on devices with Android 8.0 only.
- Restarting the device before launching android-BasicSyncAdapter does not cause the SecurityException to be thrown. Currently proposed work around for users.

I am trying to figure out how to successfully call addAccountExplicitly without having to first restart the device.

Comment: You got any solution for this crash ??

Comment: Posted an answer that the SecurityException is no longer being thrown when running on OS build 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

My Google Pixel device received a 8.1 update which I installed.  Retesting with the two applications:

1. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testdpc
2. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BasicSyncAdapter

Then following the steps to reproduce, the SecurityException is no longer being thrown.

To verify that it is not the test apps that have changed to fix the problem, I flashed my Pixel device with the specified 8.0 ROM image.  Retested and the SecurityException is thrown in the same manner.

The problem appears to be fixed after OS version 8.0.

Comment: I installed the two apps on 8.0 emulator, I didn't see any crash.

The basic reason for the crash could be one app already created the Account with same `accountType` another app is trying to create the same account or accessing the account.